# Entity Framework ASP.Net MVC return only the desired records directly from the Entity Model

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

So I'm writing an Accounting application in which each user can have multiple businesses and therefore multiple "versions" of the application. 
I have added a Business table in SQL Server and all other tables have a BusinessId.
I'm currently getting the current businessId like this in controllers:

```
public int CurrentBusiness 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return db.AspNetUsers
                 .Find(User.Identity.GetUserId())
                 .CurrentBusiness
                 .Value; 
    } 
    set { } 
}
```

Then I'm using Linq Where statements to return the relevant records:

```
db.Invoices.Where(x=>x.BusinessId == CurrentBusiness);
```

I just wanna know if it will be possible to write this code directly in my Entity Model so I can then just write:

```
db.Invoices;
```

And it returns the Invoices with the BusinessId for the current User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as your current user is managed by ASP. I think you should add a claim when  user logs in so that you do not have to query each time for `CurrentBussiness` of user.

Moving further you can create a method that returns Invoice based on Current Business of user.

```
public List<Invoice> GetUserInvoice(int businessId)
{
    return db.Invoices.Where(x=>x.BusinessId == businessId);
}
```

OR

```
public List<Invoice> GetUserInvoice()
{
    int businessId = currentUserBusinessId;// get this line from user Claim.
    return db.Invoices.Where(x=>x.BusinessId == businessId);
}
```

Good luck and happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding CurrentBusiness contains collection of invoices.

if you are [lazyloading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx) configuration than all invoices will also be included in the CurrentBusiness variable, just call like

```
var invoices = CurrentBusiness.Invoices .
```

If not than you can explicitly include while access to the db using include extension method. like

```
var business = db.Business.Include(b => b.Invoices).Where(b => b.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Hope I address your question. you should play by debugging it.

Regards,
FB